# Why i am getting 404 error when calling camunda rest api

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

When call the rest engine api of camunda unsing this url

GET http://localhost:8081/orchestrator/engine-rest/process-definition/finance-process:1:73c2ea9d-15f7-11e9-9484-00155d076c61

i am getting 404. could you please help to spot what i am missing ?

Same thing with : 
http://localhost:8081/orchestrator/rest/engine/process-definition/finance-process:1:73c2ea9d-15f7-11e9-9484-00155d076c61

i have added the rest api dependency to my pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

when calling the engine directely i get the ressource :

http://localhost:8081/orchestrator/api/engine/engine/default/process-definition/finance-process:1:73c2ea9d-15f7-11e9-9484-00155d076c61

when checking the mapped url using spring boot actuator, i can't find /engine-rest, so for sure i a missing something in the configuration.

calling http://localhost:8081/orchestrator/rest/engine
return

```
[
    {
        "name": "default"
    }
]
```

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I justed missed the engine name {default} in the url :

adding it resolved my error :

```
http://localhost:8081/orchestrator/rest/engine/default/process-definition/finance-process:1:73c2ea9d-15f7-11e9-9484-00155d076c61/xml
```